# jQuery to trigger HTML5 form validation

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, validation

I have the following HTML code of the form:

```
<form id="login_information_form" class="form uniformForm validateForm">
              <div class="field-group">
                <label for="email">Email:</label>
                <div class="field">
                  <input type="text" class="validate[required,custom[email]" size="32" id="email" name="email" value="">    
                </div>
              </div>


              <div class="field-group">
                <label for="oldpass">Old Password:</label>
                <div class="field">
                  <input type="password" class="validate[required]" size="32" id="oldpass" name="oldpass" value=""> 
                </div>
              </div> <!-- .field-group -->

              <div class="field-group">
                <label for="newpass">New Password:</label>
                <div class="field">
                  <input type="password" class="validate[required]" size="32" id="newpass" name="newpass">  
                </div>
              </div> <!-- .field-group -->

              <div class="field-group">
                <label for="newpassr">Repeat New Password</label>
                <div class="field">
                  <input type="password" class="validate[required]" size="32" id="newpassr" name="newpassr">    
                </div>
              </div> <!-- .field-group -->


              <div class="actions">                     
                <button class="btn btn-blue" id="save_login_info" type="submit">Save Password</button>
              </div> <!-- .actions -->

            </form>
```

Currently HTML5 triggers validation once the input looses its focus.

Is it possible to trigger validation with jQuery for this form when I click on Save Password button ?

**EDIT:**

My question was wrong. Can I trigger a prompt bubble for specific input field. For example: New password and Repeat new password is not correct. So I want to show a bubble on those input fields displaying the Error message

Comment: Yes you can  [See this plungin](http://jqueryvalidation.org/documentation/)  I think It's that you are looking for

Comment: HTML5 has defined a `checkValidity` method for forms (as a whole) or their individual elements, see http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#dom-form-checkvalidity

Comment: I updated the issue under the EDIT